# Finding total file descriptors throws exception

Tags: java, macos, sigar

I'm trying to find total file descriptors and found that sigar api allows to get those information. However while trying to do the below

```
Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
sigar.getProcFd(<pid>);
```

replaced the pid with an actual process if, throws the following exception:

```
 org.hyperic.sigar.SigarNotImplementedException: This method has not been implemented on this platform
at org.hyperic.sigar.SigarNotImplementedException.<clinit>(SigarNotImplementedException.java:28)
at org.hyperic.sigar.ProcFd.gather(Native Method)
at org.hyperic.sigar.ProcFd.fetch(ProcFd.java:30)
at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getProcFd(Sigar.java:531)
```

From the exception it's clear that the native Method - gather() hasn't been implemented/available on my OS (Mac OS X). How do I fix this? I tried adding the "libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib" to the classpath but with no luck.

Also, I tried creating ProcFd like below instead of getting it from sigar:

```
ProcFd proc = new ProcFd();
System.out.println("Total FD: " + proc.getTotal());
```

In this case the output is always 0. Based on the api doc it looks like it should be providing the total number of open file descriptor (http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DOUGM/hyperic-sigar-1.6.3-src/docs/javadoc/org/hyperic/sigar/ProcFd.html). Not sure if it's returning 0 because of the same reason as above i.e. missing implementation for my OS. Is that correct?

Also, wondering why is that when ProcFd is got using "sigar.getProcFd()" it throws the above mentioned exception. But when created using "ProcFd proc = new ProcFd()" it doesn't, however proc.getTotal() always returns 0?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using lsof in shell script instead of using sigar library. Never got this to work on mac. I tried in Linux and it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the documentation (http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DOUGM/hyperic-sigar-1.6.3-src/docs/javadoc/org/hyperic/sigar/ProcFd.html), and as per your finding: OSX is not supported.

```
getTotal

public long getTotal()
Get the Total number of open file descriptors.
Supported Platforms: AIX, HPUX, Linux, Solaris, Win32.

System equivalent commands:

AIX: lsof
Darwin: lsof
FreeBSD: lsof
HPUX: lsof
Linux: lsof
Solaris: lsof
Win32: 
Returns:
Total number of open file descriptors
```